# How do you prove this property? (Probability and expected value)

Tags: probability, statistics

Our teacher gave us this property and told us to just assume it's true. I'm curious as to why it's true.

$\displaystyle \sum \left[a*p(x)\right]=E(a)$

Where $E(\ )$ is the expected value and $a$ can be anything(?). How do you prove this?

Comment: The expected value is also called the mean value; $p(a)=\frac{N(a)}{N} \implies \displaystyle \sum \left[a*p(a)\right]=\frac{1}{N}\sum a* N(a)$ where $N(a)$ is the number of occurrences of $a$.

Comment: The formula in the question is wrong, actually.

Answer (score 0):

For any constant $a$, $\mathbb{E}\left[a\right]=a=\sum_{x\in \Omega_X} a p_X(x), \forall p_X(x)$ where $p_X(x)$ is any valid Probability mass function.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is true simply because it is the definition of the expecdted value E(a)

Comment: The formula is wrong and it is certainly not the definition of the expectation E(a).

Comment: Yes it is. But it is close and I assume that is what the questions means.